# Is there a Java counterpart for Spritekit's SKActions(moveBy)?

Tags: java, android, swift, android-studio, sprite-kit

I am working on converting some of my games to android after already publishing them to the IOS App store. I wanted to add a little motion to the objects on the screen. In Spritekit, you can simply use the following to move a node a certain length:

```
Node.run(SKAction.move(by: CGVector(x,y), duration: time))
```

This is very useful for giving motion to stuff on the screen and wanted to replicate it in Java. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not that easy to move objects in Android.

There is some difference in iOS and Android, where iOS provides easy to use framework, Android doesn't have any easy to use native framework.

Now how to do it, in Android?

First let's learn some basics:-

- iOS has **SpriteKit**, Android has **Canvas**
- SpriteKit can use concept of Node to display object on screen.
  Canvas uses bitmaps to draw objects on screen.

Now, it is too big of a topic to cover on Stackoverflow, but the general things, we need to do is:-

1. Draw objects on screen, where they should have been initially
2. Then we have to setup game environment is such a way, that the game runs in a while loop, and which should atleast give user, 60 FPS.
3. Then add the move object logic, inside the while loop. Thus, giving the user, the illusion that the object moved (2, 6) position in 10 seconds.

I would literally just show you the code, which does that https://bitbucket.org/jenelleteaches/android2d-pongclone/src/master/MainActivity.java

And would recommend reading this book, before moving into 2d game development in Andorid :- Android Game Programming by Example. This is published by Packt